# Flutter hot reload not working with ctrl+s

Tags: android, flutter, hot-reload, flutter-hotreload

My hot reload button is clickable working alright but if I used ctrl+s it does not reload
I'm working with android studio flutter project Please any help?

I was expecting the Ctrl+s to hot reload but no results on that unless I click on the hot reload button

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running your app using the 'flutter run' command, you can hot reload by pressing 'r' in the terminal window.